# calling repaint on jpanel causes its children to shift

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, repaint

Im currently working on a game and i hava a jpanel that has a custom button and a jlabel, and when pressing the button the game starts.
i am trying to make that panel fade in with a timer animation by using paintComponent and paintChildren but when i call repaint the button and jlabel shift to the side:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgEe9.png]

this is the code for my jpanel:

```
public class PlayAgainScreen extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private final int UNIT_SIZE;
private final Timer timer;
private int actPer = 0;

public PlayAgainScreen(SnakePanel snakePanel, boolean justLaunched) {
    this.UNIT_SIZE = SnakePanel.UNIT_SIZE;
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(UNIT_SIZE * 20, UNIT_SIZE * 15));
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    PlayButton playButton = new PlayButton(snakePanel, justLaunched);
    Image image = new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("snake_logo.png"))).getImage();
    image = image.getScaledInstance((int) (this.getPreferredSize().height * 0.5), (int) (this.getPreferredSize().height * 0.5), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, UNIT_SIZE, 0, 0);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(playButton, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    this.add(label, gbc);
    timer = new Timer(17, this);
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setColor(new Color(0x543200));
    g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
}

@Override
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
    super.paintChildren(g);
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, (int) (255 - actPer * 255 / 30F)));
    g2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    actPer++;
    repaint();
    if (actPer == 30) {
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: 1) Don't override paintChildren(). That is a standard painting method that simply paints the child components added to the panel. If you want to customize painting of the panel, then override paintComponent(). 2) Don't use backgrounds with transparency. Swing does not paint these components properly. See: [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and a couple of solutions.